# NSKeyedArchiver/Unarchiver not working with UIImage created with imageNamed in IOS8 (but works in iOS7)

Tags: ios, ios8

Running under iOS8 appears to have broken some code I use to maintain a user preference for a background image. I start with a default image (FACE1.png) and was storing that as the default preference. However, when unarchiving the image, if the default was still set the dearchived image was bad.

Here's a snippet of code to show what is going wrong

```
UIImage *segment1Image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"FACE1.png"];
if (!segment1Image) {
    NSLog(@"segment1Image nil pointer");
 } else {
    NSLog(@"The segment1Image image size is %f, %f", segment1Image.size.width, segment1Image.size.height);
    NSData *segment1ArchiveData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:segment1Image];
    if (!segment1ArchiveData) {
        NSLog(@"segment1ArchiveData nil pointer, NSKeyedArchiver couldn't create archive");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"The archive is %d bytes", [segment1ArchiveData length]);
        UIImage *unarchivedSegment1Image = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:segment1ArchiveData];
        if (!unarchivedSegment1Image) {
            NSLog(@"unarchivedSegment1Image nil pointer, NSKeyedUnarchiver couldn't restore from archive");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"The unarchivedSegment1Image image size is %f, %f", unarchivedSegment1Image.size.width, unarchivedSegment1Image.size.height);
        }
    }
}
```

Under iOS 7 the image is loaded, the archive created and the archive restored. The following output on the console is generated

The segment1Image image size is 508.000000, 642.000000
The archive is 408 bytes
The unarchivedSegment1Image image size is 508.000000, 642.000000

Under iOS8 the image is loaded, the archive is created (with a different number of byes) and when the archive is restored,the UIImage object has 0 height and width

I see the following output on the console

The segment1Image image size is 508.000000, 642.000000
The archive is 653 bytes
The unarchivedSegment1Image image size is 0.000000, 0.000000

If I

```
         NSData *fullImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(segment1Image);
```

I can create an archive of the PNG representation and unarchive that successfully, however I would like to know if there is a better work-around or a way to fix my code to unarchive a UIImage created with imageNamed